# Put requests using node.js and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, request

I'm learning how to make requests using node.js. My problem is that it generates these errors when making the requests (Cannot GET /Citaup/654fe24584f7a3d27e0a4c61) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Registro.js:146 Error: Error al actualizar la cita: Not Found
modificarCita @ Registro.js:146, I have this request structured as follows:

The driver that performs the update is the following:

```
const Cita = require('../Models/Cita');

exports.actualizarCita = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('Datos recibidos en req.body:', req.body);
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { nuevaFecha, nuevaHora, nuevoRut, nuevoExamen, nuevoMotivo, nuevoIdMedico, nuevoEquipo, nuevoRutm } = req.body;

    // Combinar fecha y hora
    const nuevaFechaHora = new Date(`${nuevaFecha}T${nuevaHora}`);
    
    const camposActualizados = {
      fecha: nuevaFechaHora,
      rutp: nuevoRut,
      idex: nuevoExamen,
      motivo: nuevoMotivo,
      idmedico: nuevoIdMedico,
      equipo: nuevoEquipo,
      rutm: nuevoRutm,
    };

    // Encuentra y actualiza la cita, y devuelve la versión actualizada
    const citaActualizada = await Cita.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      camposActualizados,
      { new: true }
    );

    console.log('Cita encontrada y actualizada:', citaActualizada);

    if (!citaActualizada) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Cita no encontrada' });
    }

    res.json(citaActualizada);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al actualizar la cita:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al actualizar la cita' });
  }
};
```

The model is the following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cita = new mongoose.Schema({
    rutp: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    idmedico: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    idex: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    motivo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    fecha: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    equipo: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    rutm: {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    }
});

const Cita = mongoose.model('Cita', cita);

module.exports = Cita;
```

The routes file is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const citaup = require('../Controllers/citaupdate');

// Ruta para crear una nueva persona
router.put('/:id', citaup.actualizarCita);

module.exports = router;
```

While the server file that uses said path is the following:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const db = require("./Database");

const app = express();

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000);

// Rutas
const p = require('./Routes/NuevaPersona');
const veru = require('./Routes/veruser');
const nusuario = require('./Routes/NuevoUsuario');
const citaf = require('./Routes/citafind');
const citau = require('./Routes/citaup');
const citac = require('./Routes/citacreate');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Solicitud recibida:', req.method, req.url);
    console.log('Cuerpo de la solicitud:', req.body);
    next();
  });

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/NPersona', p);
app.use('/Veruser', veru);
app.use('/NUsuario', nusuario);
app.use('/Citaf', citaf);
app.use('/Citac', citac);

// Actualiza tu ruta para incluir un parámetro ":id"
app.put('/Citaup/:id', citau);

db();

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log(`Servidor está corriendo en el puerto: ${app.get("port")}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Finally, the front that makes the request is the following:

```
const modificarCita = async (id, nuevaFecha, nuevaHora, nuevoRut, nuevoExamen, nuevoMotivo, nuevoIdMedico, nuevoEquipo, rut) => {
  try {
      const nuevaFechaHora = new Date(`${nuevaFecha}T${nuevaHora}`);
      
      const url = `http://localhost:5000/Citaup/${id}`;  // Agregar el id a la URL
      
      const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              fecha: nuevaFechaHora,
              nuevoRut: nuevoRut,
              nuevoExamen: nuevoExamen,
              nuevoMotivo: nuevoMotivo,
              nuevoIdMedico: nuevoIdMedico,
              nuevoEquipo: nuevoEquipo,
              nuevoRutm: rut,
          }),
      });
      
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error al actualizar la cita: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
      
      const citaActualizada = await response.json();
      console.log('Cita actualizada:', citaActualizada);
      alert("Modificación realizada exitosamente.");
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
  }
};
```

I would like to see if someone could help me, since I am new to doing this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has already been resolved, it was an error that was generated when using the dates and converting them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

maybe your request body is undefined, if it is you can try to use body parser to be able to read data from body `app.use(bodyParser.json())`.
[Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#:%7E:text=that%20is%20unsupported.-,Examples,-Express/Connect%20top)

Hope it helps

Comment: I did what you advised, but I haven't been able to find any new information. For example, the controller, when modifying it and doing some tests, cannot display the req.body that I set it to display at the beginning of said controller, therefore I deduce that it is an error in the routes, which I do not know how to correct because it does not I know why it occurs. According to what I have in my code, the request is received, but apparently it cannot find the route.

Comment: On which port your back-end runs?

Comment: 5000, and front 3000

Comment: can you provide access to your repos to me and I will try to fix it